# How admin-ajax works on Wordpress?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have a Wordpres website where users can do quizzes. Quizzes do admin-ajax calls every time that a users ask for show the quiz, check the answers, insert answers on a database...

Doing tests I see that for example if I load a quiz on different tabs like:

*Tab 1: admin-ajax call.*

*Tab 2: admin-ajax call.*

*Tab 3: admin-ajax call.*

The load time increase every time:

*Tab 1: 2 seconds to load*

*Tab 2: 4 seconds to load*

*Tab 3: 6 seconds to load*

Does that mean that admin-ajax can handle only one request at time and until is not finishing don't start processing the next?

So if I have 10 users doing a task, the user numer 10 will have to wait 2 + 2 + 2... 20 seconds to load the resource?

Thanks in advance to the experts on this

Comment: The AJAX call itself isn't -most likely- the issue here but the PHP code behind it. No one here will be able to tell you why response times are so slow without taking a look at the code so please share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help out.

Answer (score 0):

without ajax doesn't work lonely. php code are working from the backend. At a time ajax take only single request.(So if I have 10 users doing a task, the user numer 10 will have to wait 2 + 2 + 2... 20 seconds to load the resource?) that is your wrong thought.